# Rigid Body Plant - State vs. Kinematics and Accelerations

Tags: drake

Suppose that my rigid body plant is generated from a URDF file and represents a manipulator such as the Kuka arm in the examples. I have two questions:

1.) Are the generalized positions and velocities from `state_output_port()` and `state_derivative_output_port()` the same as the ones I could obtain from the `KinematicsResult` object that can be obtained from `kinematics_results_output_port()`?

2.) What is the recommended way to obtain the joint accelerations from a rigid body plant/tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RigidBodyPlant is on the way out (not officially deprecated yet, but very soon).  Please look at the MultibodyPlant toolchain instead?  `examples/manipulation_station` is roughly replacing the `examples/kuka_iiwa_arm` directory.

Comment: Hi Russ, thank you for your response. I had a look at MultibodysPlant. I'm still not sure how to access the accelerations. More specifically, I'm interested in the joint accelerations d^2/dt^2q that is qdotdot.

Comment: It's true that the accelerations are not available through an output port, but you can call [`EvalTimeDerivatives`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system.html#ae38625e953699a0433249142972eef52) to (re-)evaluate (with caching to avoid duplicate computation) the derivatives given a pointer to the MBP.  

You'll need to be a little careful -- we typically use a discrete-time (time-stepping) MBP for simulation if there are contact dynamics, but you will need to have a continuous-time version for the call to `EvalTimeDerivatives` to be meaningful.  Does that help?

Comment: Hi Russ. Yes that helps! I ended up adding an output to the MultibodyPlant class that uses `EvalGeneralizedAccelerations`.